# How do I use "access to site analytics?"

Tags: support

I just crossed a new rep threshold (5000) which allows me  "access to site analytics." What exactly is that, and how do I actually gain that access?

Comment: The privilege *access to site analytics* and how to use it is explained here: http://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/site-analytics - anything you need to know in addition?

Comment: @Takkat: Thanks. And how do I find the Help Center heading? I can look under "closed questions" but is there another way?

Comment: Like on the top bar right to the *review* menu in the *help* dropdown > *Help Center*?

Answer (score 3):

You can find this tool under *Review → Tools → stats → site analytics* or just via https://german.stackexchange.com/site-analytics.

As to what it is, you best look at the tools themselves, once you get there or at the [information about the respective privilege](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/site-analytics).